# Pull urls form <a href element from div class using VBA

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping

Team

My question would be, how to get VBA to grab only 'href URL links list'?

Here is my Code

```
Set Attach = Dr.FindElementsByXPath("//[@id='Order']")
Set aList = Dr.FindElementsByCss("#Order [title]")
X = 1 to 10
With Sheet2
            For i = 1 To X
            Sheet2.Cells(Lrow,1) = aList.item(i).Text
            Lrow = Lrow + 1
        Next
End With
Next
' do some stuff

End Sub
```

```html
<div class="attachments-files-list" id="Order">
    
    <div class="link">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" data-bind="click : downloadAttachments, visible: $root.attachmentsViewModel.attachments().length > 0">
            Click  <strong data-bind="text:$root.attachmentsViewModel.attachments().length">2</strong> Links
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="link">
        <a href="#" class="js-app-action-el" data-bind="click: $root.attachmentsViewModel.showDeleteAttachmentDialog">
        </a>
        <a href="https://URL/attachmentId=201803%2f93b14b2a-1c10-40f6-a3f6-0e83eea67bf2-check_out_2018.03.09_22%3a16%3a53.jpg&amp;overridefilename=check_out_2018.03.09_22%3a16%3a53.jpg&amp;overrideFileName=check_out_2018.03.09_22%3a16%3a53.jpg" class="js-app-action-el" data-bind="text:fileName, attr: { href: url, title: description }, style: { 'padding-left': $parent.isOutsourced() ? 30 : 0 }" target="_blank" title="check_out_2018.03.09_22:16:53.jpg" style="padding-left: 0px;">
            order_found.jpg
        </a>
    </div>
        </div>
```

Let me know if any additional information is needed.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can grap the attributes directly using xpath methods,

> Solution#1:

```
Set aList = Dr.FindElementsByXPath("//a[@class='js-app-action-el' and contains(@title,'jpg')]/@href")
X = Dr.FindElementByXPath("//strong[@data-bind='text:$root.attachmentsViewModel.attachments().length'][1]").Text
With Sheet2
       Lr = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
       For i = 1 To X
            Sheet2.Cells(Lr, 1) = aList.item(i)
            Lr = Lr + 1
        Next
End With
Next
```

This should return two values which you can process it however it fits your need,

```
Attribute='href=https://URL/Documents/GetTempLink?attachmentId=201803%2f93b14b2a-1c10-40f6-a3f6-0e83eea67bf2-check_out_2018.03.09_22%3a16%3a53.jpg&overridefilename=check_out_2018.03.09_22%3a16%3a53.jpg&overrideFileName=check_out_2018.03.09_22%3a16%3a53.jpg'
Attribute='href=https://URL/Documents/GetTempLink?attachmentId=201803%2fa21245ab-dd7f-4da0-bb31-d308f935527e-check_out_2018.03.09_22%3a15%3a47.jpg&overridefilename=check_out_2018.03.09_22%3a15%3a47.jpg&overrideFileName=check_out_2018.03.09_22%3a15%3a47.jpg'
```

> Solution#2:  use getAttribute method

```
Set aList = Dr.FindElementsByCss("#OrderAttached [title]")
X = Dr.FindElementByXPath("//strong[@data-bind='text:$root.attachmentsViewModel.attachments().length'][1]").Text
With Sheet2
       Lr = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
       For i = 1 To X
            Sheet2.Cells(Lr, 1) = aList.item(i).getAttribute("href")
            Lr = Lr + 1
        Next
End With
Next
```

Comment: Sureshmani, thanks for the fast reply. I had an error msg. for the line  "Sheet2.Cells(Lr, 1) = aList.item(i).Text". Error states: 

Runtime error -2146333080 (80131508) 
Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: Can i remove the contains() method in the XPath, since i not only pull only .jpg but also need to pull other file formats like pdf, video fomarts etc..

Comment: You can manipulate the xpath however you need as long as it identifies the right elements

Comment: Suresh, i tried different XPath like 1)Set aList = Dr.FindElementsByXPath("//a[contains(@href,'api.com')]/@href") and Set aList = Dr.FindElementsByXPath("//a[text()='api.com']/@href"), when i use F8 it is working fine, but i see the error message for the line Sheet2.Cells(Lr, 1) = aList.item(i).Text  which i have mentioned the screenshot in this post above. could you please suggest how to handle the error.

Comment: Since we are returning @href attribute directly from xpath, aList variable is not a collection of webelements and hence aList.item(i).Text method will not work. can you try with just aList.item(i)

Comment: - See updated answer (findelement to findelements )and i am adding another solutions as well.

Comment: 2nd solution is likely going to work well. the method name is getAttribute() in selenium. so there must be an equivalent in VBA. let me know. Thanks!

Comment: This time im getting "Object doesnt support this porperty or method"  on line Sheet2.Cells(Lr, 1) = aList.item(i).getAttribute("href"). I have also attached the code which i have used for IE browser.

Comment: does aList.item(i) - does that return the element object? if so getAttribute method is applicable. if not, you will need to find a way to access the webelements in aList

Comment: Sureshmani, Thanks for the support, i'm not sure where the code is going wrong.. neither of the methods are not working.. i will try to work on this. Thanks for your help.